# Hibernate generating wrong sql syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Hibernate  generating wrong sql(MySQL) query with syntax error.
given this HQL query :

> `"update GpClientContacter set id = :newKey  where id = :Key"`

Hibernate executes this sql query:

> Hibernate: `update GP_CLIENT_CONTACTER set CODE_CLIENT, NOM_RS=(?, ?) where (CODE_CLIENT, NOM_RS)=(?, ?)`

Here is exception message:

> > ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' NOM_RS=(15, 'test1') where (CODE_CLIENT, NOM_RS)=(15, 'test5')' at line 1
> >     .
> >     .
> >     org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

id is an EmbeddedId that has the codeClient and nomRs fields.
 :key and :newKey are instances of the EmbeddedId Type

Comment: Is 'id' a composite key?  The generated SQL doesn't seem to match your HQL at all.  What variables are you binding to ':newKey' and ':Key'?

Comment: id is an EmbeddedId that has codeClient and nomRs. 

:key and :newKey are instances of the EmbeddedId Type